# Force Window to have Focus When Opened

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a WPF application that communicates with a C++ MFC application over a socket connection. If a user presses a particular button in the C++ application then a new WPF window is shown.

Here is the code that gets called to launch the WPF window:

```
var window = new Window();
window.Topmost = true;
window.Show();
window.Activate();
window.Topmost = false;
```

On certain machines, the first window (and only the first window) that is shown in this manner won't have keyboard focus. It will be in front of the C++ app, but the C++ app will still have keyboard focus. Is there something else I can do to force the WPF window to take keyboard focus every time?

Comment: `window.Focus()` should do it for you.

Comment: `window.Focus()` returns false every time.

Comment: `window.Focus()` returns a boolean value identifying whether or not that window has the focus. My guess is that your window doesnt have focus when you call `Focus()`, so it will always be false.. to give your window focus, use `window.Focus() = true;`

Comment: `window.Focus()` should not return any value (but undefined), according to the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `window.Activate()` was returning `false`. Looking at that method's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate.aspx), it says,

> The rules that determine whether the window is activated are the same as those used by the Win32 SetForegroundWindow function (User32.dll).

The documentation for the [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then states:

> A process that can set the foreground window can enable another process to set the foreground window by calling the AllowSetForegroundWindow function.

So the solution was to have the C++ app use the AllowSetForegroundWindow function to give the WPF app permission to set the foreground window.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var window = new Window();    
window.Show();
window.Activate();
window.Focus();
window.Topmost = true;
window.Topmost = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Property `Focusable` on the `Window` to set to `true` and then in to call the `window.Focus()` ?