# Focus child window

Tags: c#, wpf

i am opening a child window from parent window and trying to set the focus to it when it opens. But it's not working.
Have tried this solution but still when window opens, it is on top of the parent window but it's not focused still parent window is focused.

[Force Window focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033262/force-window-to-have-focus-when-opened)

```
    private void GeneratePdfFunc(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new GeneratePdfWindow();
        window.Show();
        window.Activate();
        window.Focus();
        window.Topmost = true;
    }
```

Comment: Try `window.ShowDialog()` instead to make it a modal

Comment: @Equalsk it worked thanks :)